# libcurl binaries compiled for VS 2010 (MSVC 10)

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

I've to link libcurl to a project compiled on Windows XP with VS 2010 (MSVC 10).

The dependencies found at url http://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/deps/ are only for VC 2008 (MSVCR 9) and VS 2012 (MSVCR 11).

Does anybody know where to find compiled libcurl binaries or its dependencies (for building by its makefiles) with VS 2010 (MSVCR 10)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : open and convert the root DSW file, then compile with VS!